# Photos access on standard UIImagePickerController controls with camera as a source type

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

Take a look at [Path](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/path/id403639508?mt=8) app's camera controls.
There's a "Library" button on the right side. Is this possible with standard controls?

I assume this is a custom control set to the cameraOverlayView property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the same. They probably made a view that looks exactly like the camera app.